# How to make modal appear on first 2 pages of site visit?

Tags: cookies, popup, bootstrap-modal

I've been looking around for an answer to this question but all the related questions seem to be seeking to prevent this functionality.

Simply put, how do I make a bootstrap modal appear on the first two pages of a users visit? Right now I have a modal going with some simple cookie script that makes it appear once per visit. Is this something that is possible using cookies or some other method?

Not sure if this is helpful, but this is the cookie code i'm currently using -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
setTimeout(function(){   
if(!jQuery.cookie('modalShown')) {
  jQuery("#myemailmodal").modal('show');
  jQuery.cookie('modalShown', true);
}
  }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sessionStorage and make a counter with it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let counter = sessionStorage.getItem('counter');
    counter++;
    sessionStorage.setItem('counter',counter);
    if ( counter <= 2 )
        launchmodal();
})
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for you speedy response! Apologies for my JS noobness - would i use this code in addition to the code i currently have or would I integrate the two somehow?

Comment: changing launchmodal for $("#myemailmodal").modal('show'); should work

Comment: Thanks again @aysnc - the pop up is now appearing twice correctly, but now the timing function seems to be disabled. Currently I have my original code appearing followed by the code you provided. I tried switching the order but that did't seem to help. Would you happen to know how to set the time out function onto the code you suggested? Thanks in advance.